# Does Interrupt interrupt a blocked read call

Tags: mbed, lpc1768

If you were to read() incoming socket data in an infinite while loop, would an interrupt with top priority still run its ISR if the read() call is blocked (i.e. no data in the buffer)?

Comment: More detail required.

Comment: What OS?  Is the read() function provided by the OS?  If not, where'd it come from?

Comment: mbed OS running on LPC1768

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason the interrupt would not occur, unless you explicitly disabled interrupts before executing the `read()`.

After all, the whole idea is that it is an interrupt of one sort or another that's going to eventually unblock the call.